# JSON file store in PHP variable

Tags: php, json

When I open https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxxx I get an JSON file. I want to store it in a php variable and then use json_decode() function to convert it into a string. How can I directly store the JSON content in PHP variable by giving the link.

Comment: You can use file_get_contents().

Comment: Or you can use CURL http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php which is fast and have more options.

Comment: file_get_contents() worked out thank you

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution is to use the [http stream wraper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) with [file_get_contents()](http://docs.php.net/file_get_contents).

```
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents('theurl') );
```

If you need more control over the http request made, take a look at the [stream context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.php).

If you need more error handling take a look at [stream notifications](http://php.net/manual/de/function.stream-notification-callback.php).
You can also use

```
$fp = fopen('http://....', 'rb');
if ( !$fp ) {
  someErrorHandling();
}
$data = json_decode( stream_get_contents($fp) );
```

In that case you can combine it with [stream_get_meta_data()](http://docs.php.net/stream_get_meta_data) to get more http relaed stuff from the request/stream.

see also: [allow_url_fopen](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) (because the url wrappers can be disabled via configuration...)

Answer (score 0):

you can use file_get_contents() function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: What if the server doesn't `allow_url_fopen`? Perhaps it's a security concern. Wouldn't a simple cURL request be better?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy What if the curl extension isn't available. Wouldn't a simple url wrapper be better? ...gets circular at this point ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK Understood, and valid.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy But by all means, write an answer using the curl extension. It's a perfectly valid alternative. In some regards it's even superior (...I think; there's no alternative to multi_exec yet, is there? And the GSSAPI.)

Answer (score 0):

Using `file_get_contents` you can get the json.

> If you link gievs the josn as response.

```
$storeVar = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxxx");

$arr = json_decode($storeVar); //Here is the array
```